# How to extract command output from the multi lines shell in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

How to get the output of `kubectl describe deployment nginx | grep Image` in an environment variable?

My code:

```
stage('Deployment'){
    script {                                   
        sh """
        export KUBECONFIG=/tmp/kubeconfig
        kubectl describe deployment nginx | grep Image"""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you can access the environment variables in the pipeline scope within the `env` object, and assign values to its members to initialize new environment variables. You can also utilize the optional `returnStdout` parameter to the `sh` step method to return the `stdout` of the method, and therefore assign it to a Groovy variable (because it is within the `script` block in the pipeline).

```
script {             
  env.IMAGE = sh(script: 'export KUBECONFIG=/tmp/kubeconfig && kubectl describe deployment nginx | grep Image', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Note you would also want to place the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable within the environment directive at the `pipeline` scope instead (unless the kubeconfig will be different in different scopes):

```
pipeline {
  environment { KUBECONFIG = '/tmp/kubeconfig' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the syntax:

```
someVariable = sh(returnStdout: true, script: some_script).trim()
```